# OpenGL. Установка freeglut

Tags: visual-studio, opengl

Здравствуйте. Я пытаюсь установить freeglut и наконец-то, после 4 дней попыток, сделать хоть что нибудь уже :( . 
Я скачал отсюда freeglut: **http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/**

Положил из папки lib в архиве все файлы в: C**:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib**
Из папки include папку GL в: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include**
Из папки bin **dll'ки** в: **C:\Windows\System32** и в **C:\Windows\system** и в **C:\Windows\SysWOW64** . Почему в три папки dll'ки ? А просто во всех инструкциях пишут ставить в разные папки, я от безысходности поставил во все три. Писал на cyberforum, послали в FAQ, а там ничего.. Только **pragma comment прописать на подключение**, я пробовал — ноль результата. Ещё указал путь к **freeglut.lib** в Свойствах проекта - Компоновщик - Ввод - Дополнительные зависимости.

После таких процедур вот такая ошибка: [image: Окно VS проекта]

Я переустановил VS, но результата круглый ноль. 
Очень прошу помочь, пожалуйста!

Comment: Можно скопировать текст ошибки из студии в вопрос, а то без увеличения не разглядишь что там написано. А написано, что не удалось найти **freeglutd.lib**. Буква d означает debug. По той ссылке что представлена выше скачиваются только релизные.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на этот вопрос уже есть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110985/why-is-visual-studio-trying-to-link-freeglutd-li) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954344/freeglut-error-lnk1104). Чтобы подлючался релизный lib-файл должен быть определён дефайн NDEBUG (он обычно прописывается в настройках проекта) и FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS должна быть равна 1.

Вообще советую присмотреться к файлу **freeglut_std.h** там всё написано когда, и что будет подключаться.

Comment: Где именно эти "настройки проекта" ?

Comment: @AndrewIscom, Выделяем проект, вызываем контекстное меню, Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definition - вот тут должен быть NDEBUG (и он по умолчанию есть в релизной конфигурации, в проекте созданном студией). FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS похоже уже у вас выставлена правильно.