# Настройка freeglut

Tags: visual-studio, opengl

Только решил вот эту проблему: [OpenGL. Установка freeglut](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432886/opengl-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-freeglut) , но срзау после написания NDEBUG в Свойствах появилось вот это: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки в файле obj, я не знаю как исправить..

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем по другому)
[image: компилируется без ошибок]

1. Создаём пустой проект Win32 Console Application (ничего лишнего не подключаем, все галочки по умолчанию).
2. Добавляем код. Почти без изменений (который был на вашем скриншоте, кроме заголовочного файла iostream т.к. он тут не используется).
3. В свойствах проекта в конфигурации Release C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories пишем ".\include\"
4. Ниже в Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories пишем ".\lib\"
5. Закрываем и сохраняем настройки.
6. В папку с *.vcxproj файлом проекта копируем include и lib папки для freeglut.
7. Собираем проект в конфигурации Release.
8. В папке с *.sln (не *.vcxproj) файлом появилась папка Release в неё копируем freeglut.dll, которая лежала в bin (ту что в x64 не трогаем, по умолчанию у вас проект 32 битный).
9. Запускаем программу.

Для сборки в режиме Debug надо:

1. Для уже созданного проекта выполняем пункты 3 и 4 из предыдущей инструкции.
2. Далее одно из двух:

a) Добавляем в свойствах проекта в конфигурации Debug  C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions заменяем `_DEBUG` на `NDEBUG`. Это самый простой способ и для тестового проекта это проблем не вызовет, но если проект будет больше и будут подключены другие либы которые тоже используют этот дефайн это чревато новыми ошибками.

b) В настройках проекта ничего не меняем. Но вместо:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
```

пишем вот так:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#ifdef _DEBUG
  #define FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS 0
  #pragma comment(lib, "freeglut.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
  #pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#endif
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
```

Подключение библиотек можно было бы вынести в настройки проекта, но так проще описать. Не забываем скопировать freeglut.dll в папку Debug.

Только почти ничего не происходит, окно появляется и исчезает. Я не знаток OpenGL, просто скопировал ваш код.

Comment: Нет папки Release. Нажал Сборка -> Собрать решение.

Comment: "Только почти ничего не происходит, окно появляется и исчезает."
— так и должно быть :)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433351/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-freeglut