# Не могу установить freeglut

Tags: visual-studio, opengl

Пробую установить *freeglut*, стандартный способ не помог (тут задавал вопрос: [OpenGL. Установка freeglut](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432886/opengl-%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-freeglut?lq=1)), потом посоветовали установить в папку с проектом: [Настройка freeglut](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433084/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-freeglut) . Я сделал все как в последней ссылке, но не появилась папка `Release` и ничего не работает.

Вопрос не по теме: На 4-м скриншоте я выделил папку, хочу узнать для чего и откуда она. Раньше при создании консольного приложения *Win32* такого не было.. 
или я просто не замечал.

Необходимые скриншоты: 
[image: Компоновщик - Общие]

[image: С/С++ - Общие]

И, собственно, ошибка.. 
[image: ]![[]3]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "не помог"? Что именно не так?

Comment: Пункт 7 из пошаговой инструкции был выполнен не правильно. Смотрим на 1 и 2 скриншот в левом верхнем углу написано "Активная (Debug)", на 3 скриншоте сверху ближе к центру "Debug", на 4 и 5 видно папку "Debug". Я думал это очевидно, что надо собирать в конфигурации Release, раз настройки описаны для неё. Исправил в предыдущем ответе пункт 7.

Comment: И может не стоит плодить однотипные вопросы, а лучше изменять один дополняя его новой информацией?

Comment: Ещё у вас файлы *.vcxproj и *.sln лежат в разных папках, значит появится 2 папки Release (Debug). В предыдущем ответе обновил пункт 8.

Comment: Они стандартно так лежат, я НЕ ТРОГАЛ.

Comment: @AndrewIscom, ну лежат в разных папках и лежат. Я обновил инструкцию, попробуйте ещё разок. не обязательно все действия делать заново, просто проверить что настроено не так.

Answer (score 0):

[советуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12121716/4827341) определить символ препроцессора `FREEGLUT_STATIC`

В студии определения символов добавляются в:

> Project → Properties → Configuration Properties → C++ → Preprocessor → Preprocessor Definitions

Comment: * приложил руку к лицу *. Там говорится про банальное определение символа препроцессора. В студии это в Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, внесите исправление в ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: если хотите - поправите сами. я не считаю этот ответ действительно ответом на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, вы явно разбираетесь в *ms/windows* и *ms/visualstudio* значительно лучше меня. я правильно понимаю, что все три пункта в конце ответа надо заменить на предложенную вами строку? (ну и ссылку убрать)

Comment: в общем-то - да

Comment: Статическая сборка у него не соберётся. Вы используете компилятор mingw и соответствующие либы для него, а он msvc и там нет статических либ. `#error Static linking is not supported with this build. Please remove the FREEGLUT_STATIC preprocessor directive, or download the source code from http://freeglut.sf.net/ and build against that.`

Comment: В общем то помогло, НО VS говорит что " 1 IntelliSense: ошибка в командной строке: недопустимое макроопределение: -D FREEGLUT_STATIC"  и при это работает, как будто ошибка есть, но она ни на что не влияет. Прописал в настройках проекта: -D FREEGLUT_STATIC

Comment: @cybrex *Вы используете компилятор mingw* — если это мне, то вы ошибаетесь: у меня нет ни *ms/windows*, ни, соответственно, *mingw*, уже как минимум лет десять.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, извиняюсь, я так подумал когда посмотрел в [это описание](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/)